# XCode 4.5.1 Crashes on Install of Provisioning Profile

Tags: xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I recently upgraded to 4.5.1.  I went to add a device to my provisioning profile and XCode crashes.  It also crashes if I open the organizer and select devices.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.7.4.  Below is the stack trace:

Crashed Thread:  7  Dispatch queue: com.apple.dt.DVTCertificateUtilities.scan

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000b8

VM Regions Near 0xb8:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010c833000-000000010c836000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G1004
objc[10449]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245a67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff92459d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff905a49bf io_service_get_matching_services + 210
3   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff9055c604 IOServiceGetMatchingServices + 137
4   com.apple.framework.IOKit       0x00007fff9055c741 IOServiceGetMatchingService + 25
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955cd10b +[NSFileWrapper _canSafelyMapFilesAtPath:] + 241
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95572510 -[NSData(NSData) initWithContentsOfFile:options:error:] + 139
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5b0c22 -[NSNib _loadNibDataFromPath:] + 310
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5b0abc -[NSNib _initWithPath:bundle:] + 162
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5b0a11 -[NSNib initWithNibNamed:bundle:] + 257
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5b08f9 -[NSViewController(NSInternal) _nibWithName:bundle:] + 56
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5b07b0 -[NSViewController loadView] + 155
12  com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000111c9b466 -[DTDKDetailViewController loadView] + 51
13  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c26675 -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerScreenshotsViewController loadView] + 49
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5ac4ae -[NSViewController view] + 41
15  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c2d08d -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerViewController outlineViewSelectionDidChange:] + 194
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95563d0e __-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 + 47
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978f77ba _CFXNotificationPost + 2634
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9554ffc3 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 65
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5e9499 -[NSTableView _sendSelectionChangedNotificationForRows:columns:] + 203
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5bff5a -[NSTableView _enableSelectionPostingAndPost] + 425
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d5e8305 -[NSTableView _doSelectIndexes:byExtendingSelection:indexType:funnelThroughSingleIndexVersion:] + 2915
22  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c2aae4 -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerViewController setCurrentNodeIdentifier:] + 1442
23  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c2bb9b -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerViewController updateNodes] + 2542
24  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c29997 -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerViewController sharedViewSetup] + 219
25  com.apple.dt.IDE.IDEiPhoneSupport   0x0000000110c29a23 -[IDEiPhoneOrganizerViewController viewDidInstall] + 59
26  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cd49165 -[DVTViewController _didInstallContentView:] + 128
27  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cc83b0c -[DVTControllerContentView _viewDidInstall] + 406
28  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cc8338f -[DVTControllerContentView viewDidMoveToWindow] + 75
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d591a55 -[NSView _setWindow:] + 2618
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d58fc6d -[NSView addSubview:] + 405
31  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cd48ef0 __42-[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController]_block_invoke_0 + 164
32  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010c8c02c8 DVTInvokeWithFailureHintObject + 59
33  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cc75141 -[DVTReplacementView _setupViewController] + 249
34  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010cc75015 -[DVTReplacementView installedViewController] + 138
35  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d55ddd9 -[IDEApplicationController _openFiles:] + 533
36  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d55dbba -[IDEApplicationController application:openFiles:] + 49
37  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d7395e5 __-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:]_block_invoke_1 + 1064
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d4833e1 -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:] + 64
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d48310f -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] + 287
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d6c1f33 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenDocumentsForURLs:] + 272
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d482c5a -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 307
42  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97941541 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 65
43  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955867c7 __-[NSAppleEventManager setEventHandler:andSelector:forEventClass:andEventID:]_block_invoke_1 + 101
44  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9558574e -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 283
45  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955855dc _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 105
46  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d5f34d4 HandleOpenDocAE + 47
47  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c7c3c25 aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 200
48  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c7c3b03 _ZL25dispatchEventAndSendReplyPK6AEDescPS_ + 38
49  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8c7c39f7 aeProcessAppleEvent + 250
50  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff96443d7d AEProcessAppleEvent + 102
51  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d48007d _DPSNextEvent + 1247
52  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d47f735 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
53  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d47c071 -[NSApplication run] + 470
54  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8d6f8244 NSApplicationMain + 867
55  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010c834d17 0x10c833000 + 7447
56  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010c834ca8 0x10c833000 + 7336

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245c7e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9075378a _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9075231a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245a67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff92459d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978db50c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955b2fd7 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 335
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a772a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a76a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c2188bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245a67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff92459d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978db50c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000111c9ab1f -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 298
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a772a -[NSThread main] + 68
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a76a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c2188bf _pthread_start + 335
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245bdf2 __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9792cc8b __CFSocketManager + 1355
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c2188bf _pthread_start + 335
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245b47a __accept + 10
1   com.unity3d.Unity4XC            0x0000000110fa02e8 +[UnityXcodePlugin pluginBg] + 201
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a772a -[NSThread main] + 68
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a76a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c2188bf _pthread_start + 335
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245a67a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff92459d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978db50c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3c74 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff978e3486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95558f7b -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 267
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff95558e67 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 62
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a772a -[NSThread main] + 68
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff955a76a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c2188bf _pthread_start + 335
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb75 thread_start + 13

Thread 7 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.dt.DVTCertificateUtilities.scan
0   com.apple.security              0x00007fff976b3d98 DERDecodeSeqContentInit + 4
1   com.apple.security              0x00007fff976ad0fa parseX501NameContent + 32
2   com.apple.security              0x00007fff976ad193 SecCertificateCopyCommonNames + 62
3   com.apple.security              0x00007fff976ac49a Security::KeychainCore::CertificateValues::copyFieldValues(__CFArray const*, __CFError**) + 282
4   com.apple.security              0x00007fff97678fb3 SecCertificateCopyValues + 44
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010c93a2cc +[DVTCertificateUtilities certificateKindForCertificate:] + 62
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010c93ad0f +[DVTCertificateUtilities _scanForSigningCertificates] + 492
7   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010c8e32a0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke_0 + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90751a86 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff907532d6 _dispatch_queue_drain + 264
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90753132 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 54
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9075292c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 198
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21a3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21a594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21a594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21a594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9245c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21a594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8c21bb85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000401acd3c0  rbx: 0x00007fff976ad1b8  rcx: 0x0000000000000005  rdx: 0x00007fff976ad1b8
  rdi: 0x00000000000000b8  rsi: 0x000000011522dba8  rbp: 0x000000011522db80  rsp: 0x000000011522db80
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x00000000ffffffff  r10: 0x000000000000009e  r11: 0x0000000401acd3c0
  r12: 0x0000000401acda40  r13: 0x000000000000000f  r14: 0x0000000401acd3c0  r15: 0x0000000402e60be0
  rip: 0x00007fff976b3d98  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00000000000000b8
Logical CPU: 6
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue...tried restarting the computer, unplugging the device, all the standard stuff. My iPad was unceremoniously "un-provisioned" and now I can't re-provision it. This code-signing BS is more hassle sometimes than actually writing software. Apple really, really needs to streamline the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the obvious - restarting Xcode / rebooting?

You may have to go one step further than deleting your profiles. Try revoking existing profiles and resetting your keychain. See also: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3752773?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Yes I have.  I also deleted all provisioning profiles and restarted as well.

Comment: Resetting my keychain and rebuilding my certificates/keys worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but have you tried disconnecting any iOS devices you have attached to your mac?

I was experiencing the same problem, and tried deleting profiles and certs, restarting, etc, but no dice. When i unplugged my new iPhone 5 it worked fine. I probably have to clean up the certs on my iPhone as well.